# Get last results set from GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, resultset

I have an ASP.NET **Gridview** linked with an **SQLDataSource** and some search filters implemented through **TextBoxes**. I would like to know if there is any way to get the last result set rendered by the GridView in order to apply the filters on subsets instead of applying them to the **SelectCommand** of the **SQLDataSource**. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can get like... `GridViewRow row = grdId.Rows[grdId.Rows.Count - 1];`

It will return the last row of GridView

Comment: Akthar: thanks for your answer. I do not want to get the last row but all the resultset obatained from the last executed select command.

Comment: You can store the last command Row Index in some ViewState/Session and then you can utilize that one.

Comment: can you make an example please?